# Changing fonts in \sin, \tan, \lim…

Tags: math-mode, fonts

In LaTeX, when I type symbols as `\tan` or `\inf` in math mode, they use the normal text font, while I would want them to use Times font, without changing the main font of the text nor the math fonts, neither of which are Times. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! You have chances it will be hideous. Do you have any reason for such a choice?

Comment: ,@TorbjørnT.  I totally misunderstood the question and removed my answer. As we repeatedly say,  a MWE speeds up getting a precise answer!

Comment: What does it means, that you do not want to change the math fonts?  Do you want *all* operator names to be typeset in times?

Answer (score 11):

It's really simple. Add

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{timesoperators}{OT1}{ztmcm}{m}{n}
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symtimesoperators}
\makeatother
```

to your document preamble. Then look at the hideous output and remove the four lines. `;-)`

Comment: That's an answer I like: answering the question despite having misgivings about OP's choices....

Comment: @JPi But I didn't dare to show the output. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg How can I change the size \sin, \tan etc? I'd like to use it together with the solution on my following question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689677/how-can-i-change-the-font-and-size-of-math-mode-without-changing-the-normal-t/689719?noredirect=1#comment1711690_689719

Answer (score 1):

Some necromancy, because someone just told me they looked up the solution here, and it didn’t work for them with `fontspec`.  (Because egreg used legacy font encodings, which are very portable so long as you stick to unaccented Latin letters and digits, it doesn’t support the `fontspec` scaling commands.)

When using `fontspec` or `unicode-math`, the default font for log-like operators is `\mathrm`, which you can change with, e.g.:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmathrm{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
The sine is \(\sin x\) and the infinimum is \(\inf S\).
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Heros + TeX Gyre Termes sample]

If what you want is to change *only* the operator font and leave `\mathrm` alone, `unicode-math` has a `\setoperatorfont` command:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontface\timesfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]
\setoperatorfont\timesfont

\begin{document}
The sine is \(\sin x\) and the infinimum is \(\inf S\).
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Heros + TeX Gyre Termes sample]