# How can I change the font and size of math mode (without changing the 'normal' text font)?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontsize, exam, math-fonts

I would like to use the following fonts within my exams:

1. Normal text:  *Arial (12 pt)*
2. Math text:    *Times New Roman Mathtype (13 pt)*

I use Arial with *fontspec*. How can I change the font and size math mode?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}\noindent
    This exam is in accordance with the format of the Dutch Final Central Exams.
        \begin{questions}
            \question
            This text is \emph{Arial (12 pt)}.\\
            The following should be \emph{Times New Roman Mathtype (13 pt)}:    
               \[a^2+b^2=c^2\] and \[\alpha+\beta=\gamma\] and \[f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}x+2\pi\right)\]
            Note that also $x+y=z$ should be in \emph{Times New Roman Mathtype (13 pt)}.
                \begin{parts}
                    \part[1000]
                    How is it done?
                \end{parts}
        \end{questions}
    End of the exam.    
\end{document}
```

Hereby an example of the format of the exam:
[image: Example of the format of the exam]

And another one for the first two Greek letters:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Egreg’s approach is the same basic one I would use, but a few subtleties.

First, your text will be too small.  Here, “12 pt” almost certainly means twelve PostScript points of 1/72 inch.  That’s what PDF, Word, and almost all software made since 1984 think a “point” means.  But TeX is older than that, and has used a smaller “pt” for more than forty years.  What other software calls a pt, it calls a bp, for “big point.”  So, you’ll want to tell the document class to use `12bp`, or 1/6", instead.

However, the standard TeX classes don’t let you do that, so you’ll want to load another package to change the size:

```
\usepackage[fontsize=12bp]{scrextend}
```

You don’t give a sample of the Dutch exam style, but the intent is probably to make the letter x the same height in text and math mode, which you can do with `Scale=MatchLowercase`.  If it’s the capital letters that should line up, use `Scale=MatchUppercase` instead.  Since all other fonts should scale to the main font, it’s simpler to make this the default:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
```

Next, this specifies “Times New Roman Mathtype.”  Since there is no such font, I take it to mean Times New Roman, as used by the program Mathtype.  That’s a problem, since Mathtype takes its math symbols and Greek from Symbol, which doesn’t use a standard encoding.  You’re going to have to substitute another math font, such as XITS or TeX Gyre Termes Math.

There is a way to get Times New Roman for your math letters, if the slight differences between it and other Times clones matter to you: the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.  Be aware that some systems still have an old version of Times New Roman and Arial from the ’90s, which did not include Greek.

Which leaves us with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[fontsize=12bp]{scrextend}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
%\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[range={up,"00-"FF}]
%\setmathfont{Times New Roman Italic}[range=it]
%\setmathfont{Times New Roman Bold}[range=bfup]
%\setmathfont{Times New Roman Bold Italic}[range=bfit]

\begin{document}\noindent
    This exam is in accordance with the format of the Dutch Final Central Exams.
        \begin{questions}
            \question
            This text is \emph{Arial (12 pt)}.\\
            The following should be \emph{Times New Roman Mathtype (13 pt)}:    
            \[a^2+b^2=c^2\]
            Note that also $x+y=z$ should be in \emph{Times New Roman Mathtype (13 pt)}.\\
            And some Greek: $\Alpha\Beta\alpha\beta\symup{\alpha\beta}$. % These commands work in unicode-math.
                \begin{parts}
                    \part[1000]
                    How is it done?
                \end{parts}
        \end{questions}
    End of the exam.    
\end{document}
```

You can uncomment the `\setmathfont` command to change the font, which gives you:

[image: Arial + Times New Roman sample]

Comment: I added an example of the format to the original post. I'm not sure about the Mathtype. I asked an employee of the company how makes the exams and he told me 'Arial 12' for the text and 'times new roman 13 Math type' for the formulas.

Comment: @KenAdams From your description, I assume he means he uses the MathType software by Design Science, with those settings.

Comment: It works and looks good though. All give a closer look to compare with the other solution to see which one I prefer. But this made my day!

Comment: @KenAdams Thanks for the sample. Based on that, the exams appear to be written in ISO 80000-2 style; that is, with capital letters for variables and functions italicized and constants such as π upright. To match that, `\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}` and write `\uppi` instead of `pi`. Write `\symup{e}` for other constants, or define `\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}`.

Comment: You're right: the output of \symup{e} is in accordance with the one used on the exams. Thanks. I'll give the unicode-math package a brief study later on.

Comment: Can I change the font functions like \sin, \log etc? I tried the following solution, but that resulted in smaller size of \sin https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370948/changing-fonts-in-sin-tan-lim

Comment: @KenAdams Those should by default use your `\mathrm` font, which should by default be set to your main font. You can override this with e.g. `\setmathrm{Arial}[Ligatures={Common, TeX}, Scale=MatchLowercase]` and `\setoperatorfont\mathrm`.

Comment: @KenAdams The command you were using was for a legacy 8-bit font, which still works (as long as you stick to unaccented Latin letters and digits), but doesn’t play nice with `fontspec` or `unicode-math`. In this instance, it doesn’t know about font scaling.

Comment: So simple... But sometimes hard to find how to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: @KenAdams I went back and added a new answer to the question you found, in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: Dont know if this reaches you, but: Is it possible to have different font within the solution-environment? (If you don't read it or it's too complicated for a short answers I'll start a new topic with minimal example and description)

Comment: @KenAdams Change the font within the `\newenvironment` or `\NewDocumentEnvironment` command. If you want to also change the math font, declare a different math version and switch to that too. In `unicode-math`, this is `\setmathfont` with the `version` option.

Comment: So simple. Thanks again. I never used it before, but I I'm certain I'll use it again in another context.

Answer (score 1):

I made an experiment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily{\stix}{STIX Two Text}

\begin{document}

A{\stix A}

\sbox0{A}\the\ht0

\sbox0{\stix A}\the\ht0

\end{document}
```

[image]

Doing 8.58984/7.944 gives 1.081299 (rounding to the sixth decimal digit). Note that 13/12=1.083333.

Now if I do

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily{\stix}{STIX Two Text}[Scale=1.081299]

\begin{document}

A{\stix A}

\sbox0{A}\the\ht0

\sbox0{\stix A}\the\ht0

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

and I guess that the purpose of the specification is to have equal height for text and math.

If I implement it in your `exam` code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[Scale=1.081299]

\begin{document}\noindent
    This exam is in accordance with the format of the Dutch Final Central Exams.
        \begin{questions}
            \question
            This text is \emph{Arial (12 pt)}.\\
            The following should be \emph{Times New Roman Mathtype (13 pt)}:    
            \[a^2+b^2=c^2\]
            Note that also $x+y=z$ should be in \emph{Times New Roman Mathtype (13 pt)}.
                \begin{parts}
                    \part[1000]
                    How is it done?
                \end{parts}
        \end{questions}
    End of the exam.    
\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, here's the output with `Scale=1.083333`:

[image]

Instead of STIX Two Math you may use TeX Gyre Termes Math.

Comment: That's great. Look much better than how it used to be. Especially things sin(x) and log(x) functions which were eyesore.

Comment: @KenAdams Text in Arial and math in Times is not the best choice, IMHO, but I understand you have to cope with rules set by people probably unaware of math typography.

Comment: What is IYHO the best choice?

Comment: @KenAdams Serif for everything.